# Gnuplot: removing or moving tics at the border of graph with autoscaled tics

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to add an empty boundary around the data in an autoscaled graph without having tics in the empty boundary or at the border.

```
$ gnuplot -p -e "set offsets 0,0,0.1,0.1; plot sin(x)"
```

[image: empty boundary with tics at the border]

### Desired result

Tics are gone at the y-axis border/in the empty boundary
[image: tics are gone at the border]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set offsets 0,0,0.25,0.25
set yrange noextend
plot sin(x)
```

[image]

There is also the possibility to approach this quite differently, which may or may not be appropriate for your case.

```
set border 2
set ytics rangelimited
set xtics axis
set tics nomirror
set xzeroaxis
set offsets 0.,0.,.25,.25
plot sin(x)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are looking for `set autoscale noextend`, check `help noextend`. You can give the offset also in graph coordinates to be independent of the actual y-scale, check `help offsets`.

**Script:**

```
### autoscale noextend
reset session

set autoscale noextend
set offsets 0,0, graph 0.1, graph 0.1

plot sin(x)
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image: h]